Simple interest linear equation with one variable
Mary inherits $ 100,000$ Dollars and invests it in two certificates of deposit. One certificate pays $6$ percentage and the other pays $4.5$ percentage simple interest annually. If Mary's total interest is $5025$ Dollars per year, how much money is invested at each rate?
Let $x$ and $100,000-x$ be the amount of money in each certificate of deposit.
$0.06x+0.045(100,000-x)=5025$. Solve this equation for $x$ to get the answer.
But the equation can also be set up as $0.045x+0.06(100,000-x)=5025$ and the answer would be exactly the same. Why is it so? I don't understand the mathematical principles that make it possible to switch around $x$ and $100,000-x$ without altering the answer.

The switching is allowed because there's an implicit equation that is still satisfied. Let's look at it from a more general perspective. The question is

how much money is invested at each rate

So there are two unknowns we need to find: how much money was invested at 6% and how much money was invested at 4.5%. Let's label them as $x$ and $y$, respectively. That sets the variables.
Next, the equations. We know that all of the 100,000 was invested in the two deposits. So that gives us our first equation, $$x + y = 100, 000 \tag{1}$$
We also know that the total interest per year is 5025. That gives us our second equation, $$0.06x + 0.045y = 5025 \tag{2}$$
So we can summarize the problem mathematically as, solve for $x$ and $y$ under the following two equations,
$$ x + y = 100, 000 \\ 0.06x + 0.045y = 5025$$
A common approach to solving these problems is to express one variable in terms of the other, and substitute to reduce to a single equation in a single variable. If we choose to express $y$ in terms of $x$, we can do so by rearranging the first equation to get, $y = 100,000 - x$. Then substituting in the second equation, we get $$0.06x + 0.045(100,000 - x) = 5025$$
Did we have to rearrange the first equation? No, we could also have rearranged the second equation instead to have $y = \frac{5025 - 0.06x}{0.045}$, and then substitute in the first equation, but you can see this is more messy.
$$x + \frac{5025 - 0.06x}{0.045} = 100, 000$$
Did we have to express $y$ in terms of $x$? No, if we choose to express $x$ in terms of $y$, then we have $x = 100,000 - y$ and get  $$0.06(100,000 - x) + 0.045y = 5025$$
Coming back to your question, we can switch the $x$ and $100,000 - x$ around because the two arrangements satisfy the implicit first equation,
$$ x + (100,000 - x) = 100,000 \\ (100,000 - x) + x = 100,000$$

Certainly the value of the unknown, $x$ that emerges is different for the two equations
For the first, it yields $x= \$35,000$,
whereas for the second, it yields $x = \$65,000$
You are saying that the results are the same because both split the $\$100,000$ similarly, but depending upon how you have defined $x$, you will get different answers for $x$
There should be nothing mysterious about this !
